# SQL Server Return 4 rows for every hour in a day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that returns all messages from a device within a day (simplified):

```
    SELECT date, value 
    FROM Messages 
    WHERE date between '04/01/2018 00:00:00' AND '04/01/2018 23:59:59' 
    ORDER BY date asc
```

The problem is that it returns too many rows. For example, 1 row per minute **minimum** (1440 rows in a day), and I have to print that in a chart.

How could I return the first row in every quarter hour so I get 4 rows per every hour of the day?

Expected result:

```
        date                value  
2018-01-04 05:00:00.000  ||  5,52
2018-01-04 05:15:00.000  ||  5,48
2018-01-04 05:30:00.000  ||  5,35
2018-01-04 05:45:00.000  ||  5,42
```

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, mySQL, etc)

Comment: Just added the tag, thanks.

Comment: Are you storing the result data in a table or simply selecting? I believe you could use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and refer back to the stored data...

Comment: Is that sample table data or the expected result?

Comment: @JackNicholson I am simply selecting data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have more than one row in one minute or rows do not exactly match hour:minute pattern, you can use following:

```
SELECT * INTO tab FROM (VALUES
('2018-01-01 05:00:01', 1),
('2018-01-01 05:10', 2),
('2018-01-01 05:20', 3),
('2018-01-01 05:28', 4),
('2018-01-01 05:31', 5)
) T(Date,Value)

SELECT Date,Value FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(Date AS DATE),
                                           DATEPART(HOUR,Date),
                                           DATEPART(MINUTE,Date)/15
                              ORDER BY Date) RowNum FROM tab
) T WHERE RowNum=1
```

It returns:

```
Date                 Value
----                 -----
2018-01-01 05:00:01      1
2018-01-01 05:20         3
2018-01-01 05:31         5
```

Comment: +1 for the best answer. You could improve it a bit with this: ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(minute, 0, Date)/15 ORDER BY Date)r

Comment: This answer **helped the most** in the end, I agree, this is in fact the **best answer**. +1

Answer (score 5):

you can do it by a Modulus (%) like as follow:

```
SELECT date, value 
    FROM Messages 
    WHERE date between '04/01/2018 00:00:00' AND '04/01/2018 23:59:59'  and (datepart(minute,date) % 15) = 0
    ORDER BY date asc;
```

This query returns a data which contains a date row which minute completely divide with 15 (Quarter). I think this may solve your problem.

> Note: I not used **`Seconds`** because of your data added per minute as per
>   your language in question.

Comment: This works great, the only issue is if I had more than 1 row in that minute it would still return several rows. How could I filter that?

Comment: But you quoted that your data inserted per minute.

Comment: 1 insert per minute minimum, there can be several messages in a minute.

Comment: So you want the last added data of this minute or your datepart for second also follow a pattern to insert.

Comment: the first row in a quarter hour would be great.

Comment: You can use FORMAT(cast('2017-12-01 12:12:22' as datetime),'hh:mm:ss') with group by to get only first data per minute. like `SELECT date, value 
    FROM Messages 
    WHERE date between '04/01/2018 00:00:00' AND '04/01/2018 23:59:59'  and (datepart(minute,date) % 15) = 0
  group by  FORMAT(cast(date  as datetime),'hh:mm') ORDER BY date asc;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162728/discussion-between-addy-and-addo-lou).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a "like" condition:

```
and date like '%00:00.000' or date like '15:00.000' ...
```

Comment: I don't think this will give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a modulo function on the minute part of the date

```
select *
from mytable T1
where datepart(minute, T1.date)%15 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by getting a row_number partitioned by 15 minute intervals.

```
SELECT Truncdate, value FROM (
    SELECT date
         , value
         , dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, date) / 15 * 15, 0) AS TruncDate
         , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, date) / 15 * 15, 0) ORDER BY date) as RowNum
    FROM messages
    ) x
WHERE x.rownum = 1
```

You can change Truncdate to date in the outer select if you want to see the actual first datetime in that 15 minute block instead of the block-rounded date.

e: I didn't actually read the question. This approach has the advantage that it will still get the first value in each block even if it occurs after the minute the block starts, which I now notice isn't a requirement for your solution.